# Use of multiple sockets in Multithreaded UDP server

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

```
Requirement:
```

I need to write a server that should be able to receive multiple client connections(FCFS order) and be able to process each client in a separate thread, so that the processing looks like as if all the clients are served concurrently. The transport protocol being employed should be UDP. Also several round trips of data transfer would happen between client and server, and the data that is received from the client has to be stored at the server side for further processing with respect to this client.

```
Implementation:
```

To achieve this, I employed a queue/threadpool mechanism. Initially I create a pool of fixed number of threads and have a queue datastructure to store client-addresses. This queue is shared among all threads, and hence I used "mutex" to lock/unlock this queue. In the main server thread, I create a socket, bind it to a global port/address and then I block the server on "recvfrom" call. Any client that wants to communicate with the server sends a "Hi" message to the main thread server listening on the global port-address. The main server thread upon receiving this "Hi" datagram pushes the client's sockaddr structure onto the queue and goes back to block on the "recvfrom" call to accept other clients.

Any of the pool threads that gets a lock on the queue, pops the client's address and starts processing this client all by itself. That is, the pool thread will now create a socket, bind it to a different port than the global port and sends this port-address to the client using the client's address it has popped off. At the client side, after sending the "Hi" message, it blocks on "recvfrom" call and once it receives a message from the server(with a different port), it stores this port/address and from then on, it communicates with the server only using this new port sent by the pool server thread.

```
Clarification needed:
```

I have noticed in many Stack overflow questions that A SINGLE SOCKET is always sufficient in multithreaded UDP server, but according to my requirements I think I need multiple UDP sockets, each one catering to a client. Please provide me suggestions on my approach of threaded UDP server for my requirements

**EDIT: Improved the design**

Thanks for all your comments and discussions about my design. After grasping all your views on single-socket connection and context switching,  I have an improved design in mind. Please provide feedback on my improved design

In this implementation, I am going to use only one global UDP socket that is bound to a globally known port-address. Just like before, I will create a fixed number of threads initially, say 5 threads. Then I perform recvfrom() on the single socket in all my threads. Whichever thread receives the datagram first, will be able to know three things out of this datagram:

- Client sockaddr(Address of the client)
- Client data(Actual data sent)
- Process number(Sent along with the data. This is to let the server know  what kind of processing has to be done on the client data)

Based on the information above, the server thread will process the data based on the process number and sent reply to the same client from which it received. After processing data and sending the reply(if necessary), this thread will go back to blocking on the recvfrom() call.

Also, details about various clients would be stored in global hash table and maps(accessible to all threads), so that any thread could access it to process according to that particular client.

**Changes at the client side:** The server should be able to know what processing it has to do on the client data. Hence the client would send process number along with the data.

Comment: Why do you have such awful requirements?! Why would you want to arrange things so that to do a tiny bit of work for each of 100 clients you need to do 100 context switches? I would do anything I possibly could to change the requirements to something consistent with decent performance. "You can't do this work unless you get exactly the right thread running" is the worst possible model.

Comment: There is no such thing as receiving a UDP connection, and there is no reason to use multiple UDP sockets. Your requirement doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once socket is enough because you are able to identify the client each time you receive a packet by calling recvfrom by using its source address (src_addr):

```
recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
             struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Now, this solution has a single reception point. That means the server has to receive the data and then pass it to the thread that should perform the process. This reduce the parallelism of the single socket solution since you are using one port only.

<del>In my opinion your solution is better in terms of parallelism since your threads are running on different ports, so they can serve several clients in parallel specially if your machine has several processors and several network cards that could be used to attend your clients. In the best case you may have several threads running in parallel, in different processors each one serving a client coming from different network interface.</del>

**EDIT**:

After discussing your design with David, he convinced me that having several sockets would lead to several context switches which may slow down the server performance. So the best in this case is to use several threads but a single socket for all the clients.

Comment: Why does this require a single reception point? He can have as many threads as he wants call `recvfrom` on the same socket. (And his solution is awful for parallelism. As soon as a thread finishes doing work for a client, ti will be unable to continue running and a context switch will be forced.)

Comment: I'm assuming that threads once "assigned" to one client they should only serve packets from this client. If any thread could server any client then it's OK to have several threads calling recvfrom on the same port. Newly this is a single reception point since all of them are listening on the same UDP port.

Comment: One thing has nothing to do with the other. If you're going to have a single socket, you can use a thread pool or a thread per server. Both approaches work. You can also have either a single thread blocked in `recvfrom` or more than one. Both approaches work. The difference is, with only one thread blocked in `recvfrom`, you *must* dispatch the packet to another thread for service, because otherwise you could only process one packet at a time. (Unless you conveyed to another thread to block in `recvfrom`.)

Comment: I understand from your answer when you say 'his solution is aweful from parallelism' that you are assuming a machine with 1 processor

Comment: It makes no difference how many processors his machine has. The argument is the same regardless. Say his CPUs are idle and he receives 100 datagrams from 100 different clients. How many context switches will he need to process them all and return the CPUs to idle state? This number is independent of the number of CPUs and results solely from his awful solution.

Comment: Why not? could you give more details please. Because as I see it if you have several processors you can run several threads in parallel, one on each processor receiving data from different UDP ports (as he described in his solution).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90620/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-redobot).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Thanks for your discussion. It was very much helpful. Please look at my revised design(in EDIT). I think I have made a proper implementation this time.

Comment: So, the points are: 
1.) single socket has best throughput, 2.) recvfrom() is an extended version of recv(), which also gets the sender's address
3.) the sender's address can be used to delegate a packet to a sender-specific session/thread
4.) in sum you can manage one session for each peer socket address

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure where those requirements are coming from - mostly, are those for real life program or for some sort of assignment/interview/etc.

I will continue on presumption this is a real-life program, since I am not helping anybody with assignments :)

UDP is not connection-oriented protocol (even though UDP sockets can be 'connected', but this just adds confusion). It is a message-oriented protocol. Now, the first question in designing thread model is always 'do I need thread model here?' You will need thread if you have operations which can be performed independently of each other and take noticeable time. In your case, it depends on what you really do with the message. Let's assume, you have some processing on it and this process time is significant as compared to number of potential simultaneous cliens (remember, there are successfull single-thread Web servers! There is nothing wrong in simply doing all your requests single-threaded).

Design-wise, I do not think the idea of giving new port to the client to connect is a good idea. There are several reasons for this, and one of those might be a firewall between your client and server. Implementation-wise it is also not straightforward, and somehow imitates TCP with UDP. If you need TCP, use TCP, do not try to build TCP over UDP - you will not succeed.

What I suggest instead is have a single listener on the socket, which would dispatch requests (together with sender information) to worker threads, which will send the reply back to the client. Remember, for UDP you do not need to send response over the same socket you used to process request.

Comment: You can equally well have more than one listener blocked in `recvfrom` on the same socket if you want. Then you don't even need to dispatch requests if you don't want to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, true. I personally prefer a single 'master', because I mostly deal with the middleware where you can only have onle listener per enry point.

Comment: It's definitely simpler to have only a single thread blocked in `recvfrom`, and that's so rarely going to be a performance-limiting factor. The exception might be if you deal with a very large number of requests that take very little computational effort to service.

Comment: _even though UDP sockets can be 'connected', but this just adds confusion_ Maybe confusing, but this is a very important fact!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i dont see how having single thread blocked in `recvfrom` is "simpler". It requires some inter-thread-communications for dispatch requests and then grab result back. Compare this to model. where each thread is independent and do it's own "recv -> handle -> send" logic.